# Tomee Server and Application Resources and how to reference in JNDI or using @Resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, resources, apache-tomee

Tomee has several locations where Resources can be defined:

- Inherited from Tomcat/Catalina

  - Server

    - ${catalina_home}/conf/server.xml
    - ${catalina_home}/conf/context.xml
  - Application

    - ${catalina_home}/conf/Catalina/localhost/appcontext.xml
    - ${webapp}/META-INF/context.xml
- Introduced by Tomee

  - Server

    - ${catalina_home}/conf/tomee.xml
    - ${catalina_home}/system.properties
  - Application

    - ${webapp}/WEB-INF/resources.xml
    - Not sure, but I assume also some per application properties.

This is all confusing to me. I simply want to install a connection pool at `java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb`.

There are additional several notes I want to take:

- I might want to consider defining the resource server side - so passwords are not part of the deployment.
- I might want to consider the choice of one connection pool instantiated per webapp deployed, or one globally connection pool shared for all webapps.
- I might want to restrict a connection pool (with given username/password) for just one webapp, although not deployed with the webapp (hence the choice of `conf/Catalina/localhost/appcontext.xml`).
- I am aware of following documentation:

  - [Tomee Directory Structure](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-directory-structure.html)
  - [Tomee Application Resources](http://tomee.apache.org/application-resources.html)
  - [Tomee Admin/Configuration/Resources](http://tomee.apache.org/admin/configuration/resources.html)
  - [Tomee Datasources](http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-datasources.html)

I did test out setting a simple resource in WEB-INF/resources.xml, and it was reachable as simply `jdbc/mydb` used for example in a `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`. I did not have the same success when defining the resource in `conf/Catalina/localhost/appcontext.xml`.

It also seems to me that Tomee has a special way for choosing root contexts where services and our resources are deployed. During startup I see attempts to remap some of the resources. Example output:

```
[...].createRecipe Creating Resource(id=webapp/jdbc/mydb)
[...].AutoConfig.processResourceRef Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/webapp/jdbc/mydb' in bean MyService to Resource(id=webapp/jdbc/mydb)
```

And from [Tomee Documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-datasources.html):

> ```
> <Resource id="Derby Database"  type="DataSource">
>   . . . . .
> </Resource>
> ```
>
> The global jndi name would be java:openejb/Resource/Derby Database

So how do I refer to that in a portable way?

It seems I can solve that by simply putting this in the `WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
```

This allows me to access this in JNDI as `java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb`.

My apologies for inserting parts of answer here - but I am just adding info to this as I find it. Later,  I will either move this into answers, or leave as is if someone finds a better satisfying answer.

I hope to understand:

- What the mechanisms are for instantiating resources (when)
- How they are reachable (directly through JNDI, `persistence.xml`, and or a `@Resource` tag).
- Any standard practices around those resources